# How can I access which environment is set in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, environment-variables

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have found that, in order to manage multiple environments, CodeIgniter uses the following function in index.php

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

to define the environment.

My question is, how can I get which environment set at index.php inside my controllers?

Comment: `ENVIRONMENT` itself is the constant, its like a variable
so you can save it in a variable or use it directly like :
`$evn = ENVIRONMENT`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ENVIRONMENT` is defined in `index.php` that is `pipeline` of each CI application file, you can access anywhere e.g model, view, controller, library

```
echo ENVIRONMENT;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your index.php file, try something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'dev' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')
{
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}
elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'staging.example.com')
{
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'staging');
}
else
{
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
```

Obviously, set it up with values that make sense for you. However, this will set the ENVIRONMENT based on where the application is running, automatically.